# Convert column name & value into each row in hive sql

Tags: sql, hive

My data looks like this:

| ID | acno | date | tranym |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 12345 | 20170505 | 201705 |
| BB | 67890 | 20180604 | 201806 |

I want to change like this:

| col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| ID | AA |
| acno | 12345 |
| date ​ | 20170505 |
| tranym | 201705 |
| ID | BB |
| acno | 67890 |
| date ​ | 20180604 |
| tranym | 201806 |

I really appreciate detailed explanation of solution.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is (This is same as unpivot which

```
select 'ID',id from hive_table union all
select 'acno',acno from hive_table union all
select 'date_col',date_col from hive_table
```